# Click event is not working on link inside contenteditable div in iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, wkwebview

Everything seem OK but when I apply click or perform any other event is not working inside iOS WKWebView  with contenteditable. I assumed there is no errors in code. But I think I need to set up something else I don't know.
I need help to overcome with this problem. If there is any trick or alternative please suggest.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    //Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var containerViewForWKWebView : UIView! //Set background color to very light grey color.

    //Variables
    var webView: WKWebView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //Initializing webView
        webView = WKWebView()
        //Setting delegate and other additional settings for webView
        webView?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        webView?.navigationDelegate = self
        webView?.uiDelegate = self
        webView?.scrollView.bounces = false
        webView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black //Setting webView background color to black.

        //Now adding webView inside containerViewForWKWebView.
        containerViewForWKWebView.addSubview(webView!)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        //Updating layout for webView.
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: containerViewForWKWebView.bounds.width, height: containerViewForWKWebView.bounds.height)
        webView?.frame = frame
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func webPageForCheckboxTest(_ sender: UIButton) {

        loadLocalWebPageFromBundleMain(webPageFileName: "local-web-page-for-checkbox")
    }

    @IBAction func intertnetPageForCheckboxTest(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let webSiteAddress = URL(string: "http://juntolife.com/for_testing/web-page-for-checkbox.html")
        let myURLRequest = URLRequest(url: webSiteAddress!)
        webView?.load(myURLRequest)
    }

    @IBAction func webPageForClickEventTest(_ sender: UIButton) {

        loadLocalWebPageFromBundleMain(webPageFileName: "local-web-page-for-clickevent")
    }

    @IBAction func internetPageForClickEventTest(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let webSiteAddress = URL(string: "http://juntolife.com/for_testing/web-page-for-clickevent.html")
        let myURLRequest = URLRequest(url: webSiteAddress!)
        webView?.load(myURLRequest)
    }

    func loadLocalWebPageFromBundleMain(webPageFileName: String) {

        var htmlString: String!
        let webPageURLFromBundleMain = Bundle.main.url(forResource: webPageFileName, withExtension: "html")
        let baseURL = webPageURLFromBundleMain?.deletingLastPathComponent()
        print("Base URL of Bundle Main: \(baseURL)")

        do {
            let fileContent = try String(contentsOf: webPageURLFromBundleMain!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            htmlString = fileContent
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Failed getting content of the file: \(webPageURLFromBundleMain), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
            htmlString = ""
        }

        if htmlString != "" {
            webView?.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: baseURL)
        } else {
            print("Local web page file is not found in bundle main.")
            htmlString = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h3>Local web page file is not found in bundle main.</h3></body></html>"
        }
    }
}
```

**local-web-page-for-clickevent.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:#bce0ff;">
        <div>
            <h3 style="text-align: center;"><strong>Local Web Page For Click Event Test</strong></h3>

            <p>Link outside content editable: <a href="#"> This is a dummy link</a> Please click it to see it is working or not.</p>
        </div>

        <div contenteditable="true" id="content" style="background-color:#ffffff;">
            <p>Link inside content editable: <a href="#"> This is a dummy link</a> Please click it to see it is working or not.</p>
        </div>
        <script>
            document.querySelector("body").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
              var anchor = e.target.closest('a');
              if(anchor !== null) {
                anchor.innerHTML = Date();
              }
            }, false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**local-web-page-for-checkbox.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:#bce0ff;">
        <div>
            <h3 style="text-align: center;"><strong>Local Web Page For Check Box Test</strong></h3>

            <p>Check box outside content editable: <input type="checkbox" /> This is a checkbox input. Please check it to see it is working or not.</p>
        </div>

        <div contenteditable="true" id="content" style="background-color:#ffffff;">
            <p>Check box inside content editable: <input type="checkbox" /> This is a checkbox input. Please check it to see it is working or not.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you used Evernote? It is working on their app under contenteditable.

Comment: No, I haven't, ever. Delegate the events?

Comment: @Teemu in jQuery or in Swift?

Comment: w3schools: The delegate() method was deprecated in version 3.0. Use the on() method instead.

Comment: @Wolf I have tried your suggestion but I need continuous content editing mode. I am trying to build a rich text editor. So I need click event on images or on checkbox. But iOS doesn't allowing it. Any other help?

Comment: @Teemu I have tried following:

Comment: $("a").on("click", function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});

Comment: This is the alternative code for delegate. But this is also not working.. Any other idea?

Comment: That's not delegating, attach the event to the contenteditable, like `$("#content").on("click", "a", function(){ $(this).css('background-color', 'red'); });`

Comment: @Teemu No luck! I am working on making contenteditable = false and then making it true.. It's working but this act hiding the keypad

Comment: Add a click listener to `#content` with vanilla JS, and check `e.target` on a click, that is supposed to be `a` element when you're clicking on one.